# perl: return no content back to browser

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I'm passing a url (from javascript) to a perl script. The perl script gets data back from the URL, processes it and writes a file. That's all working fine.

At this point all I want to return processing to the browser/javascript but I'm struggling to prevent the perl script from returning content to the browser. It just blanks the page.

I suspect it's the content type/header that's causing the issue but can't seem to find a way to inhibit it returning something the browser wants to display.

So far after much hunting I came across

```
print "Status: 204 No Content\n\n";
```

Looked promising but I suspect just having the print command is enough to push something back at the browser.

Any pointers appreciated. I can't be the only person that just wants perl to go off and do a job without returning content.

Comment: Search for "ajax" javascript calls - it sounds like you are just doing a GET/POST call. That will replace the current page, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a response to the request, and the 204 No Content *will* push something back to the browser: the information that there is no content to display (so browsers will continue to display the previous content).